# Where is whitespace between burger icon and search bar coming from?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, searchbar

How can I get the SearchBar to appear immediately right of the hamburger icon (please see image), where is the white space coming from? I cant find it.

Iv set stackLayout and SearchBar inside NavigationPage to `HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"

is it from padding from the burgerIcon button. How can I check, I cant find it either in the code?

Thanks for any replies

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"x:Class="WineShop.Views.Products">
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <SearchBar x:Name="SearchBar" TextChanged="SearchBar_TextChanged" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Placeholder="Search..." PlaceholderColor="Gray" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Name="shoppingCartImg" Icon="shoppingCartImg.png" Priority="0" Order="Primary" Activated="ShoppingCartClicked"/>
        <ToolbarItem Text="{Binding NoItemsInShoppingCart}" Priority="0" Order="Primary" Activated="ShoppingCartClicked"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: How the hamburger button is defined?

Comment: im not sure, when you create a new project with 'master detail' template it comes preloaded. So im not sure where its defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the below lines to your `Toolbar.xml` :

```
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
```

Comment: doing this and setting HorizontalOptions to FillAndExpand for StackLayout and SearchBar resolved the issue thanks so much for the help Leo